# Updating ApplicationData record from the HTML client

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

**HTML Client Lightswitch:**

In a ViewDetials screen i have a button where i would like to update my ApplicationData. However, the screens Dataworkspace does not contain the table i would like to update. My current button execute code looks like:

```
var filter = "SerialNumber eq " + screen.Hardware.SerialNumber; // Filter to find the Hardware Serial number in the active details window.
myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Scans.filter(filter).execute().then(function (result) {
    var scan = result.results[0];
    scan.NoSticker = false; // Set the property to false
    myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.saveChanges();
});
```

What I'm trying to do is update the `NoSticker` property on a record in the Scans table that matches the SerialNumber on my details screen. If i understand what I've been reading correctly, because the record is not in the screens Dataworkspace i have to query the Scans table in my ApplicationData. I can't recall ever having to do a query or a query with a filter in JS so I'm not sure If I'm even doing this correctly. When i click the button, nothing happens. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, and assuming your SerialNumber is alphanumeric, the only issue with your approach appears to be the styling of your filter expression which should be as follows:

```js
var filter = "SerialNumber eq " + msls._toODataString(screen.Hardware.SerialNumber, ":String");
```

This uses the standard LightSwitch library function to correctly markup your serial number value in the filter expression.  In this case it basically wraps the value in single quotes as follows:

```js
"SerialNumber eq 'ABC123'"
```

The _toODataString function also supports the following additional options for the second dataType parameters (covering the various LightSwitch data types):

```js
":Binary", ":Binary?"
":Date", ":DateTime", ":Date?", ":DateTime?"
":DateTimeOffset", ":DateTimeOffset?"
":Decimal", ":Decimal?"
":Guid", ":Guid?"
":Int64", ":Int64?"
":Single", ":Single?"
":String", ":String?"
":TimeSpan", ":TimeSpan?"
":Byte", ":Byte?", ":Boolean", ":Boolean?", ":Double", ":Double?", ":Int16", ":Int16?", ":Int32", ":Int32?", ":SByte", ":SByte?"
```

Each of the groups above use the same markup approach e.g. ":Decimal" and ":Decimal?" are both suffixed by an M data type identifier.  These markup options are a feature of the [oData v3 protocol's filter operation](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#thefiltersystemqueryoption) used by LightSwitch.

As an alternative, you could always add a query against your Scans table which accepts the SerialNumber as a parameter and then call it as follows:

```js
myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.ScanBySerialNumberQuery(screen.Hardware.SerialNumber).execute().then(function onComplete(result) {
    if (result && result.results && result.results.length !== 0) {
        var scan = result.results[0];
        if (scan) {
            scan.NoSticker = false; // Set the property to false
            myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.saveChanges();
        }
    }
});
```

If you're still experiencing issues after trying the above approaches, the other aspect you could check is that your screen.Hardware.SerialNumber property is available at the point you're executing the search.  If not, you may need to do the following:

```js
screen.getHardware().then(function onComplete(hw) {
    if (hw) {
        myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.ScanBySerialNumber(hw.SerialNumber).execute().then(function onComplete(result) {
            if (result && result.results && result.results.length !== 0) {
                var scan = result.results[0];
                if (scan) {
                    scan.NoSticker = false; // Set the property to false
                    myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.saveChanges();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This did the trick. I had no clue you could do this from the client. I'll defiantly be using this again in the future. thank you!